# Connect Livebox to alpha and share the internet

Tags: router, alpha

I have bought an ORANGE - LIVEBOX 2 SAGEM that has a usb3 input. 
I don't have wired network at home, so i want to use my Alfa Wifi Network Adapter (awus036h) as a "source of internet". 
When i plugged the alpha in and accessed to the Livebox interface i didn't see any Wireless networks to choose from. So i did my researches in how to configure this stuff but i didn't find any helpful tutorials for my situation. 
I wish that i was clear to explain my problem. Your help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to plug anything on "your" livebox , it's already a access point .

Comment: you need to review your answer, it is not helpful for anyone. You need to answer, as per the user problem.